# Geolocation.requestPermissions not implemented for browser and error is always uncaught?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, capacitor

```
import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";

  const request_perm = () => {
    try {
      const stuff = Geolocation.requestPermissions();
      console.log(stuff, "stuff");
    } catch (err) {
      console(err, "err");
    }
  };
```

as you can see, the call to `Geolocation.requestPermissions` is wrapped inside a `try block`, so I don't see why it is still an uncaught error:

[image]

The error goes away if use the `await` like so:

```
  const request_perm = async () => {
    try {
      const stuff = await Geolocation.requestPermissions();
      console.log(stuff, "stuff");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, "err");
    }
  };
```

It is still not implemented, however the error is now caught by the catch block.

Comment: `The error goes away` so, it works with `async`/`await`?

Comment: It is still not implemented for the browser, however the error is caught and does crash the APP.

Comment: Well, it does say that it's "Not implemented on web" - I guess it's meant for native apps (ionic specifically)

Comment: but I still don't understand why the error is not caught despite the try catch

Comment: try/catch won't catch asynchronous errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how javascript works for this question. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) is a great explanation about js event loop & callback queue.

In short, the [Gelocation.requestPermissions()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/geolocation#requestpermissions) function returns a Promise, which means it is an async function. If it is not called in async function & await clause is not in front of the call, the javascript engine won't wait until the promise becomes settled, running the rest of the functions.

Which means `console.log` below the `requestPermissions` call will be run and try-catch clause will end before the promise becomes settled -> goes inside task queue(microstask queue actually) -> waits for the call stack to be empty